# What does True (.T.) and False (.F.) mean

Tags: translate, step

I am having a STEP file and I'm wondering what the following boolean value stands for.

`#34=ADVANCED_FACE('',(#46),#40,.F.);`

Does anyone know the answer? I can't seem to find proper information about STEP files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4th attribute for entity `advanced_face` is called `same_sense`.

[Source](http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/express/ap203e2/html/t_advan-03.html)

Comment: Have you figured out what "same_sense" actually means? The documentation ends at saying that's the name of the attribute, but doesn't give any indication what it actually means for the part/edge/face... @user2479356